# Capturing mouseover on multiple slider elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-tag-manager

## What are you trying to do?

I'm trying to track mouse-hover over tooltips on each slide of a carousel slider (example of a carousel slider: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDoWr.jpg)). Each slide has anywhere from 3-5 tooltips that are visible. When a mouse hovers the tooltip, a data layer event fires.

Each tooltip has the same class variable and no ID. The code updates to include or remove a tooltip line depending on the slide visible.

Example HTML: Slide 1

```
<div id="container">
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 140px; left: 260px;" tooltip="0"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 80px; left: 450px;" tooltip="1"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 200px; left: 730px;" tooltip="2"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 300px; left: 700px;" tooltip="3"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 550px; left: 840px;" tooltip="4"></div>
</div>
```

Example HTML: Slide 2

```
<div id="container">
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 140px; left: 260px;" tooltip="0"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 80px; left: 450px;" tooltip="1"></div>
<div class="tooltip" style="top: 200px; left: 730px;" tooltip="2"></div>
</div>
```

## What is your code that currently tries to do that?

```
<script>

function hover(eClass) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(eClass);
  for (var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
  }
  function mouseOver() {
        dataLayer.push({
        'event':'elementHover'
    });

    var elem = null;
    var i = null;
  }
}  

hover("tooltip")

</script>
```

## What do you expect the result to be?

I expect the dataLayer event to fire anytime a tooltip is hovered on the carousel slider, no matter what slide it is on (1st, 2nd, 5th). I try to reset the *elem* var and *i* var after each hover so the script gets the newest number of slide tooltips but I must be doing it wrong.

## What is the actual result?

The javascript code works and fires an event for tooltip mouse-hovers on the *first slide only*. When I go to the previous or next slide, the script no longer fires an event when I mouseover a tooltip.

Comment: Can you apply the event listener after each slide change?  in other words, probably call `hover("tooltip")` whenever the slide changes.

Comment: I think it is because before slides shows, the elements are not rendered in html, which means they cannot be get by "getElementsByClassName", so the tooltip shows afterwards there are no eventlistener binded. What you can do is dynamically do addEventListener or add CSS "hover" to your tooltip.

Comment: @snapjs - Wow. Rookie oversight on my part. Easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to apply the event listener after each slide change (i.e., call `hover("tooltip")` when the slide changes to ensure the event listener is applied to DOM elements after they exist).

Comment: Yup! Rookie oversight on my part. Thanks for quick fix.